# div height 100% on mobile page

Tags: css, mobile, height, viewport

I am trying create mobile eDM.
I want showed 100% height, on mobile pages.
I want to use css instead of Jquery.

hear are html

```
    <div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
        <!-- first -->
        <div class="item">
            <div class="firstWrap">
                <div class="fw_1"><img src="images/first_global.png" alt="rocket"></div>
                <div class="fw_2"><img src="images/global_text.png" alt="글로벌 비즈니스 진출을 준비 중이십니까?"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- //first -->

        <!-- second -->
        <div class="item">
            <div class="secondWrap">
                <div class="sw_1"><img src="images/second_infra.png"></div>
                <div class="sw_2"><img src="images/infra_text.png"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- //second -->
</body>
```

and Css

```
body {overflow-y:hidden; margin:0 auto;}

/* header */
.header {width:100%; max-width:720px; height:auto; margin:0 auto;}
.header img {display:block; margin:0 aut0;}

.item {width:100%; height:100%; max-width:720px; margin:0 auto;}

/* first */
.firstWrap {width:100%; max-width:720px; min-height:100%; background:#003f69;}
.fw_1 {padding:35.3% 35.6% 10%;}
.fw_1 img {width:100%; margin:0 auto;}
.fw_2 {padding:0 10.9% 46.3%;}
.fw_2 img {width:100%; margin:0 auto;}

/* second */
.secondWrap {width:100%; max-width:720px; min-height:100%; background:#f04e37;}
.sw_1 {padding:35.3% 35.6% 10%;}
.sw_1 img {width:100%; margin:0 auto;}
.sw_2 {padding:0 6.8% 46.1%;}
.sw_2 img {width:100%; margin:0 auto;}

#owl-demo .item img{
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }
```

URL: http://chn0627.dothome.co.kr/test/

please Let me know,

Comment: i mean i wanna showed 100% full screen(on any devices) without scrolling(scroll Bar)

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't 100% clear to me, to what do you want to add a 100% height?

I guess that `#owl-demo` is the main 'container' of your website. Add `min-height: 100%` to it.

In order to make that function, you'll need to set the height of the parent as well (otherwise it will only be as high as its content). So add this to your CSS:

```
html, body {
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

[Offtopic]

Please note a small typo in your CSS:

```
.header img {display:block; margin:0 aut0;}
```

Should be

```
.header img {display:block; margin:0 auto;}
```

Comment: thanks. 
I mean I want to showed hole contents(all divs) 100% full screen without scrolling(scroll bar). I tried following your tip, but It doesn't work.